# How to capture the output of a bash script from a C program?

Tags: c, linux, bash

I want to save the output from a bash script which is invoked from a C program to a variable declared in the C program. I searched and tried successfully calling a script using `system`, and I tried this, but it didn't work:

```
char* a;
system("a=`ls`");
printf("%s",a);
```

Comment: bash variables have utterly and absolutely NOTHING to do with any variables you defined in your C app.

Comment: You're assigning to a shell variable with no relation to your C variable. You will need to create a pipe and set the child's STDOUT to be the writer end of that pipe. This means you won't be able to use `system`

Comment: one way, though messy, is to '>' the script output to a file.  then, after the script exits, the C program opens that file for input and reads in the output from the script.  Something like: system("ls > /tmp/LS_Output");  FILE * pLSO = fopen( "LS_Output", "r");

Answer (score 1):

Use popen() system call. You can pass the cmd as the parameter. You will get the command output as text when the function returns. Hope this helps.

Comment: An answer with the same content has already been given to this question earlier (see the answer on the top marked as accepted).